# How can I insert a variable in the object PivotLines( ) when sorting a column in a PivotTable with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, pivot-table

I have a **pivot table** in Excel with the quantity of points scored by each student at 3 exercises,
I would like to sort data from exercise in descending order using a VBA code so I can find out which student made the better score in exercise 3. My real table is much bigger, so I need to make a code for that.

```
Student    exercise 1   exercise 2   exercise 3   Total
Mary          2            10            5         17
Peter         6             2           11         18
Karen        20             7           14         41
Total        28            19           30         77
```

Here's my code:

```
Sub SortDescending()

    Dim Cell1  As Range
    Dim Cell2  As Range

    'Seeting the cell Mary ex1 to the variable Cell1
    Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(columnOffset:=-1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Select
    Set Cell1 = ActiveCell

    'Setting the cell Karen ex3 to the variable Celula2
    Range("A2").End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(columnOffset:=-1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=-1).Activate
    Set Cell2 = ActiveCell

    'Sorting the penultimate column
    Cell1.Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica1").PivotFields("Supp Desc").AutoSort _
    xlDescending, "Student", ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "Tabela dinâmica1").PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(3), 1    

End Sub
```

I wanted to insert PivotLines(Cell1) instead of the number 3 in the argument.
Or make the **sorting descending code** work for PivotTables **without knowing cell's position**.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly I believe in your code you are reverting the order of the fields, "Student" should be in the place of "Supp Desc" and viceversa.

Let's try this:

```
Sub SortByExercise3()

Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("SheetWithTablaDinamica").PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica1")
PvtTbl.PivotFields("Student").AutoSort Order:=xlDescending, Field:="Sum of Exercise3"

End Sub
```

Results:

[image]

Take care that the name of the fields of your Pivot Table is the same with the name of the fields in your VBA code.

Comment: The problem is that I want to insert a graphic with these information and automatically refresh this pivot table as I add new exercises. So I would have to substitute Field:="Sum of Exercise3" for a variable that represents the penultimate cell, so the scores of the penultimate exercise can be shown in my graphic.